# clean url with htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to 'clean up' my urls from looking like this

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/index.php?pid=graphicdesign
```

to looking like this

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/graphicdesign
```

I have tried using htaccess but I can't get it to work, any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome.
htaccess code that i've tried is below (the first line is what was already in the file as put there by my web host)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/(\w+)*$ ./index.php?pid=$1
```

I have also tried variations where I remove the / from after the ^, the ./ from before index, the . from before index and the * from before $ but none of these variations seem to make a difference.

Thanks for your helps guys!

Comment: Are you redirect to a wrong URL or aren't you redirect at all ?

Comment: it just doesn't do anything, so if I click on the graphic design link it goes to http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/index.php?pid=graphicdesign ok but doesn't strip the index.php?pid= from the url like I would like it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your links on are in the from like this

```
http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/graphicdesign
```

And use this code in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: how do i make sure my links are in the form you mentioned - that is how i want them to end up after the htaccess cleans them up - originally they are in the form http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/index.php?pid=graphicdesign

Comment: ive tried copying and pasting the above code just as it is but that didn't work, the urls continued to show up in the form http://www.smokescreencreative.co.uk/index.php?pid=graphicdesign

Comment: .htaccess doesn't change links. The purpose of the rewrite is so that when someone goes to http://www.somescreencreative.co.uk/grahicdesign that it goes to the correct page because internally it redirects to index.php?pid=graphicdesign. It doesn't change the links. You have to make sure all the links on the page are the way you want it to be in the address bar. Understand?

Comment: that's great, thankyou! It worked :) As I'm a complete noob with htaccess would it be possible to ask for a very quick explanation of how the above code works and what it's doing? Once again thanks for the help! :)